# How can I insert many documents at once?

Tags: couchdb

When I want to insert a document using CouchDB, I send a request like this one:

```
POST http://localhost:5984/blogging/
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Example",
    "value": 5
}
```

And it Works. But, what if I want to insert two documents at once? I try:

```
POST http://localhost:5984/blogging/
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

[
    {
        "name": "Example 2",
        "value": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "Example 3",
        "value": 7
    }
]
```

And it answers me:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2019 08:03:52 GMT
Server: CouchDB/2.3.0 (Erlang OTP/19)
X-Couch-Request-ID: 9ed2f39fcf
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0

{
  "error": "bad_request",
  "reason": "Document must be a JSON object"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, I would suggest you to check this API from the documentation: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs

And, apart from that, you aren't sending a valid JSON object. I would change your request in this way:

```
POST http://localhost:5984/blogging/_bulk_docs
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "docs": [
        {
            "name": "Example 2",
            "value": 6
        },
        {
            "name": "Example 3",
            "value": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can we use Update Handler to insert if not exists / update if exists many documents at once?